# How to process multiple files based on their names?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, if-statement

With below code Im collecting files from multiple directories. I check their dates, check if they are present in list `missing_dates` and I check if that specific date is present in every directory. After that, I process those files with the same date to 1 file.

Short said: 3 files of same date in every directory gets proccesed to 1 file.

This is my code:

```
missing_dates = ['20200907', '20200908', '20200909']

root=Path(r'c:\data\FF\Desktop\new_location\middle_stage_preprocessed_district')

data_per_date = dict()
for missing_date in missing_dates:
    print(f"processing {missing_date}")
    files=[fn for fn in (e for e in root.glob(f"**/*_{missing_date}.txt") if e.is_file())]
    if len(files) != 3:
        # stop processing, check other date
        continue

    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r') as log_file:
            reader = csv.reader(log_file, delimiter = ',')
            next(reader) # skip header
            for row in reader:
                if filter_row(row):
                    vehicle_loc_dict[(row[9], location_token(row))].append(row)

    data_per_date[missing_date] = vehicle_loc_dict  
                                                                                             
for date in missing_dates:
    file_name = "MM{}-AB.dat".format(date)
    full_path = os.path.join(my_files, 'Directory_X', file_name)
    with open(full_path, 'w+') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = '\t')
        writer.writerow(headers)
        writer.writerow(data)
        vehicle_loc = data_per_date[date]
        for vehicle_loc_list in vehicle_loc.values():
            for record_group in group_records(vehicle_loc_list):
                writer.writerow(output_record(record_group))
```

My file structure is like this:

```
├── dir_1
│   ├── XX_20200907.txt
│   └── XX_20200908.txt
├── dir_2
│   ├── YY_20200907.txt
│   └── YY_20200908.txt
└── dir_3
    ├── ZZ_20200907.txt
    └── ZZ_20200908.txt
```

I receive below error, but I dont know why.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\data\FF\Desktop\Python\Python\Official_part1.py", line 271, in <module>
    vehicle_loc = data_per_date[date]

KeyError: '20200909'
```

Comment: 1) share your file official_part1.py   2) the error is at line 271: probably there is not the key `20200909`. You can add an `if control` to give an error but continuing or use the `try` structure and so on. There are many different ways to do that. Basically, you are accessing a dictionary with a key that does not exist. What do you want to do? continuing processing the file and give a WARNING? you can!

Comment: @Leos313 True, there is no key `20200909` because its not present in my structure as well. `official_part1.py` is just the name of my script...

Comment: I knew it was the name of your script. I have just asked if you can share it so we can read it! :)

Comment: @Leos313... I have shared my script in my question. Line 271 is the line `vehicle_loc = data_per_date[date]`.  Its weird thats its grabbing the date 20200909 because thats a date which is only present in `missing_dates` and not in my file structure..

Answer (score 1):

Simply the keyword `20200909` is not present in your dictionary. You can add a control mechanism that **catch** your error and **through** a warning, an error, an **exception**. There are many ways of solving your problem. The question for you is: what do you want to do? exit with an error? continuing processing?

Comment: I prefer no errors at all so I would like my code to continue with the keywords that ARE present... How can this be done?

Comment: I guess a simply Try and Except block should do the trick

Comment: @TangerCity, https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp